# When are properties in closures evaluated?

Tags: c#, lambda, closures

Several methods in our code base use a 'MaybeObject' that can be passed into functions when a result might be known, or might rely on an external webservice call that has not yet been carried out. For example, the property below can either have a specified known value, or if not specified and called after the async call is complete it will return the result of the Async call.

```
private string _internalString;
public string stringProp
{ 
    get
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_internalString))
            return _internalString;
        return resultOfAsyncCallFromSomewhereElse;
    }

    set { _internalString = value; }
}
```

Obviously, trying to reference the property before the async call is complete would cause a null reference exception so we also have a flag to check if the value is available.

The question is, in the code below would the creation of the lambda try and evaluate `stringProp` (which might not be populated yet), or would evaluation be deferred until the resulting Action is called (which would be after checking the async operation is complete)?

```
public Action ExampleMethod(MaybeObject maybe)
{
    return () => doSomethingWithString(maybe.stringProp);
}
```

Comment: My guess would be that you can't be sure and that in the spec's both are valid situations. Let's see what complete answers say.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Evaluation will be deferred until the resulting Action is called.**

The code referenced by a delegate is only executed when the delegate itself is explicitly invoked, **regardless of how the delegate itself was created**.

For example, these ways of passing the code to execute through the [Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action.aspx) delegate are all equivalent, and the `doSomethingWithString` method won't be executed until a call to `Action()` is made:

**Explicit method (.NET 1.1):**

```
private MaybeObject maybe;

public Action ExampleMethod()
{
    return new Action(DoSomethingWithMaybeObject);
}

private void DoSomethingWithMaybeObject()
{
    doSomethingWithString(maybe.stringProp)
}
```

**Anonymous method (.NET 2.0):**

```
public Action ExampleMethod(MaybeObject maybe)
{
    return delegate() { doSomethingWithString(maybe.stringProp) };
}
```

**Lambda (.NET 3.5):**

```
public Action ExampleMethod(MaybeObject maybe)
{
    return () => doSomethingWithString(maybe.stringProp);
}
```

**See also:**

- [Delegates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)
- [Anonymous Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yw3tz5k%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)
- [Lambda Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx)

Answer (score 6):

In C# all would be evaluated whilst execution since C# lambda Closures is not a true Closure which able to resolve a state of captured environment in moment of creation.

```
() => doSomethingWithString(maybe.stringProp);
```

Here is even reference `maybe` could be null and you won't got any issues like NullReferenceException until executing a delegate. This trick sometimes used for late-bound value resolving.

[Wikipedia: Closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29):

> A closure retains a reference to the environment **at the time it
>   was created** (for example, to the current value of a local variable
>   in the enclosing scope) while a generic anonymous function need not do
>   this.

Nice overview of C# Closure specifics - [Anonymous methods and closures in C#](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/abhinaba/archive/2005/08/08/448939.aspx)

> From the definition of Closure it can be inferred that Closure
>   remembers the values of the variables during its creation. However in
>   C# the outer local variable (i in this case) is shared with the
>   anonymous method by creating it on the heap. This means any change to
>   it in the anonymous method changes the original value and when the
>   method is called the second time it gets the modified value of i as 1
>   (see second line of output). This leads many to argue that anonymous
>   method is not actually a Closure as by its definition the value of a
>   variable at the time of creation of the Closure should be remembered
>   and not modifiable.

Comment: +1 'not a true closure' - interesting point, never thought of it like that before.

Answer (score 3):

Properties in closures are not evaluated until the action is run because properties are methods, not values. Accessing MyObject.MyProperty is like calling the code MyObject.get_MyProperty(), so you can get different behavior when using a property vs. using the underlying variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
In .net closures are passed as reference so they are executed as they are evaluated, the same reason you can do something like this.


EventHandler handler = null;
handler = (sender, args) => { // event handler do something};
SomeEvent += handler;
```

Answer (score 0):

it would be deffered.
ExampleMethod() returns a delegate to the anonymous function () => doSomethingWithString(maybe.stringProp), so doSomethingWithString() won't be called until that delegate is called

Answer (score 0):

You should try this yourself to see what happens!

In this case it seems the closure is really around the `MaybeObject`, not just the string property (because the object is passed to the Action). The string property is not accessed until the Action is executed.

But even if the string itself were the variable given to the closure...

```
string s = "";
Func<bool> isGood = () => s == "Good"; 

s = "Good";
Console.WriteLine(isGood());

// prints 'True'
```

You can see here that the closure is made around a string, but it isn't evaluated until execution.

Delegates work just like any other function - they don't actually do anything until they are called.